# Sending mail using C# (Does it needs specific IIS configuration)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, iis, sendmail

I have just installed IIS, and I want to enable sending emails through C#.I don't know what I need to configure in IIS.
I tried few things but invain. I'm very beginner in ASP.net.

The code I use is the following one.

```
// create mail message object
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = @"asaf.tobi@gmail.com";// put the from address here
mail.To = @"asaf.tobi@gmail.com"; // put to address here
mail.Subject = "test";  // put subject here 
mail.Body = "test";// put body of email here
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost"; // put smtp server you will use here 
// and then send the mail
```

Comment: It's quite likely you'll want to use a SMTP server that runs elsewhere in many scenarios. Look at how your email program is setup to use your ISP or companies email server. But then again don't we all just use the browser for email ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under IIS7 you need to go to your mail settings inside the IIS Manager.

Take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(WS.10).aspx

In short

- Go to IIS Manager
- Go to the top level site to configure for all of the server or go to your specific site
- Open the Feartures View
- Open SMTP Email
- Set the appropriate mail details

If you need to install a mail server, take a gander at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/751/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7/ for details.